# Angular scope inheritance- How to use directive's enclosing scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have gotten a WYSIWYG component. I am trying yo integrate it into a form- I am unable to pass values between the directive and the enclosing controller. Why?

```
<span ng-controller="testerctrl">

<wysiwyg textarea-id="question" textarea-class="form-control"  textarea-height="280px" textarea-name="textareaQuestion" textarea-required ng-model="myvaries" enable-bootstrap-title="false">
```

```
    '<div id="{{textareaId}}" style="resize:vertical;height:{{textareaHeight || \'80px\'}}; overflow:auto" contentEditable="true" class="{{textareaClass}} wysiwyg-textarea" rows="{{textareaRows}}" name="{{textareaName}}" required="{{textareaRequired}}" placeholder="{{textareaPlaceholder}}" ng-model="value"></div>' +
      '</div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
  value: '=ngModel',
  textareaHeight: '@textareaHeight',
  textareaName: '@textareaName',
  textareaPlaceholder: '@textareaPlaceholder',
  textareaClass: '@textareaClass',
  textareaRequired: '@textareaRequired',
  textareaId: '@textareaId',
},


function($scope){

$scope.myvaries="val"


}
```

Comment: Are you using [textangular](http://textangular.com/)? I think this already does what you are trying to achieve, if I am not wrong.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-wysiwyg